# Eliminar información con PHP usando la librería de SweetAlert2

Tags: php, mvc, sweetalert2

```
El código si elimina porque ya lo comprobé, pero el problema es que no se mandar la información al controlador se toca la opción si, y cancelar la ejecución al seleccionar no.
```

Este es el código de SweetAlert2 se elimina si toco si, si toco no, se elimina igualmente, entonces me gustaría saber cómo ponerlo para solucionarlo.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function eliminarActividad(id,foto){
    Swal.fire({
  title: "<h4>¿Estas seguro que desea Eliminar a este complemento " + id + "?</h4>",
  text: "Si elmina ne se puede recuperar",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
})
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
        swal("Archivo Borrado Correctamente",{
                   icon: "success",
        },location.href = "controladores/actividadControlador.php?action=delete&id="+ id + "&foto="+ foto
        );
      }else{
        swal("El Archivo no se a Borrado"); 
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: agrega el php inicialmente te puedo decir que te faltaría esto  if (result.willDelete) ósea confirmar el resultado  hay estas cogiendo los dos resultados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba revisando los ejemplos de [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)  donde encontre 2 ejemplos para lo que buscas, agrego el mas corto que encontre:

**Tomado de SweetAlert2:**

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
  showDenyButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: `Save`,
  denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
}).then((result) => {
  /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
    Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
  }
})
```

Donde resumiendo, la estructura es `else if` que en tu caso solo usas `else`, de igual manera te invito a visitar la pagina de SweetAlert2, asi te orientas mejor con los ejemplos.

Comment: muchas  gracias si me función